# Python Tkinter Click on a Image and display a larger version in the same screen

Tags: python, image, tkinter, click, display

I would like to ask how to make a GUI that provides me with a larger version of the image in a frame that I have marked. Currently, I can show all the thumbnail on the left hand side but I couldn't figure out how to click them and if I click them how to call their larger version. Could you please help me to figure it out?
[image]

```
# TODO 0: IMPORT REQUIRED LIBRARIES AND MODULES
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


# TODO 1: CREATE A CLASS
class EditScreen:
    def __init__(self, file_directory_list):
        self.edit_window_init()
        self.file_directory_list = list(file_directory_list)
        self.image_temporary_memory=[]
        self.display_selected_images()
        self.edit_window.mainloop()

    # TODO 2: CREATE A NEW EDIT SCREEN
    def edit_window_init(self):
        self.edit_window = Toplevel()
        self.edit_window.title("Edit")
        self.edit_window.geometry('1200x800')
        self.edit_window.resizable(False,False)
        self.background_color = "#F8F1F1"
        self.my_font_color = "#0A065D"
        self.my_font = 'Poppins'

    # TODO 3: DISPLAY SELECTED IMAGES IN THIS SCREEN
    def display_selected_images(self):
        # CREATE A MAIN FRAME
        thumbnail_main_frame= Frame(self.edit_window, height=1200,width=300)
        thumbnail_main_frame.pack(side="left", fill=BOTH,expand=1)
        # CREATE A CANVAS
        thumbnail_canvas = Canvas(thumbnail_main_frame)
        thumbnail_canvas.pack(side="left", fill=BOTH,expand=1)
        # ADD SCROLL BAR TO THE CANVAS
        myscrollbar = Scrollbar(thumbnail_canvas, orient="vertical",command=thumbnail_canvas.yview)
        myscrollbar.pack(side="right",fill=Y)
        # CONFIGURE THE CANVAS
        thumbnail_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=myscrollbar.set)
        thumbnail_canvas.bind("<Configure>",lambda e:thumbnail_canvas.configure(scrollregion=thumbnail_canvas.bbox("all")))

        # TODO 3.1: PUT ALL SELECTED IMAGES THUMBNAIL TO LEFT HAND SIDE OF THE EDIT SCREEN
        # CREATE ANOTHER FRAME INSIDE OF THE CANVAS
        thumbnail_subframe=Frame(thumbnail_canvas)
        # ADD THIS NEW FRAME TO A WINDOW IN THE CANVAS
        thumbnail_canvas.create_window((0,0), width=300,window=thumbnail_subframe,anchor="nw")
        for selected_image_directory in self.file_directory_list:
            selected_image=Image.open(selected_image_directory).resize((240,140))
            self.image_temporary_memory.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(selected_image))
            Label(thumbnail_subframe,image=self.image_temporary_memory[-1]).grid()

        # TODO 3.2: WHEN ONE CLICKS ON THUMBNAIL, DISPLAY THE IMAGE
        
# TODO 4: GET THE WATERMARK TEXT

# TODO 5: MAKE CONFIGURATIONS MENU

    # TODO 5.1: SIZE

    # TODO 5.2: COLOR

    # TODO 5.3: FONT

    # TODO 5.4: LOCATION

    # TODO 5.5: OPACITY

# TODO 6: ADD OR DELETE PHOTOS

# TODO 7: SAVE THE EDITED IMAGES
```

Comment: This question is very broad. Can you explain more about why you can't figure out how to click on a thumbnail to see a bigger picture? Do you understand how to do bindings (call a function when a user clicks something)? Do you understand how to change an image displayed in another widget? What particular part of the problem are you struggling with?

Comment: first: you could display images on `Button` instead of `Label` and then you could use `command=your_function` to run function when you click image. OR you can use `your_label.bind('<Button1>', your_function)` to execute function when you click label. It needs to assign label to variable. Second: you will have to load original image from file because you don't keep image with original size when you create small version.